# How to resolve dropping wifi issue since Yosemite upgrade?

Tags: network, wifi, macbook-pro, macos, bug

As of today I experience random wifi connection drops on my MacBook Air 2012 that force me to reselect the network every ten minutes. The only recent change to the system was an upgrade to Yosemite. A google search indicated that [others have the problem as well](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6601867), yet as of yet I could not find a solution.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Apple released OS X 10.10.1 today which is expected to fix Wi-Fi issues (which was the first entry in the changelog). You might want to give that a try (after updating your backup, of course).

Answer (score 3):

Apple released the 10.10.1 update today, which is supposed to fix many wifi issues.

Comment: I have it installed and experienced yet another connection drop today. So wile it may fix it for some, I consider this not a solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I think only Apple can fix this, hopefully with an update to Yosemite (which is reportedly already being tested, but a release date is unknown).

Until then, all I can offer is a workaround.

### Find Your WiFi "port"

First you need to find your Wi-Fi port. On a MacBook Air this is probably en0.

On a Mac with built-in Ethernet and Wi-Fi, the Wi-Fi is *probably* `en1`.

If you aren't sure, you can use this:

```
WIFI=`/usr/sbin/networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder |\
egrep Device |\
fgrep Wi-Fi |\
sed 's#.*(Hardware Port: Wi-Fi, Device: ##g ; s#)##g'`
```

and then do

```
echo "$WIFI"
```

to see what it is.

### Use the `airport` command

Since Snow Leopard (at least) there has been an `airport` tool at:

`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport`

Let's call that `$AIRPORT` for short:

`AIRPORT='/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport'`

So if we put that together, this *should* be the proper command to tell your Mac to join the strongest Wi-Fi signal available:

`${AIRPORT} ${WIFI} prefs JoinMode=Strongest JoinModeFallback=KeepLooking`

which is just another way of writing this:

`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport en0 prefs JoinMode=Strongest JoinModeFallback=KeepLooking`

### Use `launchd`

You can automatically run that `airport` command periodically with `launchd`.

I have put together the necessary files at https://github.com/tjluoma/airport-autojoin but the idea is this:

- Use `launchd` plist in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/` (which must be owned by root:wheel)
- Have that `launchd` plist watch `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/` for changes
- Run the above command whenever changes occur.

I am not experiencing this problem in Yosemite, so I cannot guarantee that this will fix it, but it's what I would do to fix it if it kept happening to me.

See the [GitHub](https://github.com/tjluoma/airport-autojoin) page for more detailed instructions, including removal.

Comment: I am not able at the moment to walk myself through this in-depth workaround (I found one myself: use a LAN cable over network USB hub).

In case no better answer will come in, I grant you the bounty, yet will not accept this answer for now.

Comment: +1 to both question and answer - I feel that it will need 10.10.1 to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues all the way through 10.10.4, the following fixed the issue on my Early 2013 MBP.

- Disable WiFi
- Open *Finder*
- Press `Cmd+Shft+G` to go to the folder `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/`
- Delete (or move) the following files:

  - `com.apple.airport.preferences.plist`
  - `NetworkInterfaces.plist`
  - `preferences.plist`
- Restart your computer
- Re-enable WiFi